eslint `ignores` property has no effect on scanned files
I can't seem to get eslint to correctly directories in my project.
Using eslint config inspector, I can see my ignores look correct.
const globals = require("globals");

module.exports =[{
    languageOptions: {
        globals: {
            ...globals.commonjs,
            ...globals.node,
            ...globals.mocha,
        },

        ecmaVersion: 2022,
        sourceType: "module",
    },

    rules: {
        "no-const-assign": "warn"
    },

    ignores: ["media/mermaid.min.js"]
}];

Result:


The media folder is in the root of the project and I am running commands while in the project root directory. In addition to trying a specific file as per the screenshot, I have tried the following patterns without success:

**/media/**
media/**
media/**/*.js
media/*
media
**/*.js (as a test)

I have also tried setting the eslint working directory via .vscode/settings.json but that had no effect.
Using eslint -c eslint.config.js . in the project root directory produces the same result as eslint .. Both appear to detect the correct config file and corroborate the eslint config inspector.
node: v22.10.0
eslint: v9.13.0

It seems like the documentation for how to use the ignores property is misleading. Try specifying it as a separate configuration:
module.exports =[
 {
   ignores: ["media/mermaid.min.js"]
 },
 {
  languageOptions: {
      globals: {
          ...globals.commonjs,
          ...globals.node,
          ...globals.mocha,
      },

      ecmaVersion: 2022,
      sourceType: "module",
  },

  rules: {
      "no-const-assign": "warn"
  }
}];

See discussion.
